# How private inheritance allowed me to create object?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, inheritance, private

I have simple code, which I assume to be failed.

I have privately inherit `Shield` from `Sealer`, and even `Shield` is not it's `friend`, still I am able to create object of `Shield`.

```
class Sealer
{
public:

    Sealer()
    {
        cout<<"base constructor;"<<endl;
    }

};

class Shield : private Sealer
{
public:

    void p()
    {
        cout<<"P gets called;"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()                          
{
    Shield d;  //success here
    d.p(); // here too
    return 0;
}
```

How it is possible? Base class constructor should not be accessible. Isn't it?

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: The base class constructor is public. Of course it's accessible. If you mean in the derived class, constructors aren't inherited (until you do it explicitly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class Shield : private Sealer` means that everything in `Sealer` is kept private within `Shield`; it cannot be seen outside `Shield` or in classes derived from it.

It does not magically go back and make `Sealer`'s constructor private so that `Shield` cannot access it.  What would be the point of private inheritance if the child class could not access anything from the base class?  It would do exactly nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This does not means that `Sealer` is private relative to `Shield` (`Sealer` member access from `Shield` is controlled via access category declaration), it simply means that the inheritance is private, means that this is not externally observable (you can manipulate `Shield` as you like but not has `Shield` instance).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `private` inheritance, you cannot access the base class functionality through the derived class. You cannot create a base class pointer or a reference from the derived class.

```
class Sealer
{
   public:

      Sealer() {}
      void p()
      {
         cout<<"P gets called;"<<endl;
      }

};

class Shield : private Sealer
{
};

int main()                          
{
    Shield d;
    d.p();         // Not allowed.
    Sealer& p = d; // Not allowed.
    return 0;
}
```